# Can rules be used to run certain test methods

Tags: unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I have question related to creating test methods in my coded UI test.
Is it possible to create like rules or like an if else statement tree that would execute certain test methods to run when certain things happening or when i'm on a certain counter?.

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this.  I was going to do it in a 1 huge block of code but i dont really like the direction that is going in, since the application i'm testing has to account for different paths.

I want to create and have test methods run based on these if else statements code blocks.

If anyone has done this any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your tests to be as small as possible and test only one thing.
For multiple reasons you want to [test in isolation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8516) and not make tests depended on each other. What you are trying todo sounds very unmaintainable on the long run.

Also when a single test steps fails, you might need to run a long test to see the actual fail, making debuging harder and slower.

I would follow the [AAA pattern](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/why-and-what-is-arrange-act-assert/) in your tests to guide you

- Arrange: Setup the state of the application including data
- Act: The action you want to test. (e.g fill in a form and submit)
- Assert: Verify the action was correct by checking one thing

It is possible to group tests and run only a subset, for details see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Comment: Hi Niels, Thanks for your answer.  I think the problem i was having with automating this web app is there is one action that doesnt have action sequence that i can separate.  So i was wondering if there was a better way to test when you have a web app with actions that are dependent on other actions.  So i ended up having to create 1 action with a long code of if and else statement and switches to handle the dependencies